# in_array not finding present items from defined array

Tags: php, opencart

I am having an issue with in_array not seeming to find a value in an array. The array is constructed of categories and information from several tables but this is all well formed (relatively!). The purpose of the code is, if the row has the correct value in $level (supplied in the function), and the category_id is not already found in the array then it should be added. If it is found in the array it should be removed from the array altogether. I have been through debugging and it seems that in_array is never returning positive so i assume i have made a mistake in implementation here. See code below:

```
$sql = 'SELECT c.category_id, cd.name, cp.level ' .
       'FROM oc_category c ' . 
       'LEFT JOIN c_category_description cd ' .
       'ON cd.category_id = c.category_id ' .
       'LEFT JOIN oc_category_path cp ' .
       'ON cp.category_id = c.category_id';

$categories = $mysqli->query($sql);

$i = 0;
while($row = $categories->fetch_array())
{
    if ($row['level'] == $level)
    {
        if (in_array($row['category_id'], $cat_level_1))
        {
            unset($cat_level_1[$i]);    
            $i++;
        }
        else
        {
            $cat_level_1[] = $row['category_id'];
            $i++;
        }
    }   
}
```

Currently the output from this (truncated to 7 rows) is:

```
array (size=40)
  0 => string '17' (length=2)
  1 => string '18' (length=2)
  2 => string '20' (length=2)
  3 => string '24' (length=2)
  4 => string '25' (length=2)
  5 => string '26' (length=2)
```

Any ideas as to what mistake i have made would be appreciated!

Sam

Comment: for this part of the code:                             if (in_array($row['category_id'], $cat_level_1)) {
where is  $cat_level_1  coming from?

Comment: You only unset at $i. In every case it will only unset the last index of the array since you increment after every turn. After the array has unset once you'll have outpaced the index from the actual array.  $i will always be greater than the number of elements.  I made the assumption that you're building $cat_level_1 as you go and that it doesn't already have stuff in it.

Comment: Its undefined until it enters the loop, because it always has to go through the else first to pick up a value - I probably should define it before above but it would just be empty.

Comment: Why do you not do this all in the SQL instead of slurping every row from the join and testing in PHP?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is `unset($cat_level_1[$i]);`

You are setting `$i` to start at 0, and any time you find that `$row['category_id']` is somewhere inside `$cat_level_1` you erase the very first entry, not the actual entry that matched the `$row['category_id']`.

You probably want to use `array_search()` function instead, it will return you the key to the found item, if you set `$i` to that key then your code might have better results.

Comment: I thought it was that for a while but i returned an auto incrementing check var inside the if in_array check that always returns 0, i would expect this to return a positive number if the issue was with unset...  if a check variable is set inside the else it returns the same number as the values in the array

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that you are unsetting the wrong item in the `$cat_level_1`.  You use `in_array` to check if an item is in your category array, and if it is, you remove the an item in the list starting at index 0 instead of the actual item you want to remove.  Example: You have an array [1, 5, 10], you test if `5` is inside your array, if it is, you end up removing the `1` leaving you with an array [5, 10] when you actually wanted to remove the `5` leaving you with array [1, 10].

Comment: Thanks for that but i think that may be a separate issue, i have added a new variable to check if it gets inside the if statement and it doesn't, it returns 0 - see code below

if (in_array($row['category_id'], $cat_level_1)) {      unset($cat_level_1[$i]);        $c++;
}

Comment: (in the above $c is the variable returning 0 whereas if the in_array check was performing as expected it would be returning an incremented number)

Comment: In that case, I would check to make sure `category_id` is the exact name of the column, and that you aren't missing any capital letters (case sensitive).  Even if your SELECT statement pulls the column like this `c.cAtEgOrY_iD`, the resulting row array will always have keys that match the case of the actual column name in the database.  I would also check column `level` for the same thing just in case.

Answer (score 0):

So what Your code does is:

- create empty array `$cat_level_1` where the first level categories will be stored
- select all the categories (!!!)
- loop over them
- in each loop check whether the categories are of level `$level` which I guess is set to `1` somewhere before (maybe posting of whole logic code would be better)

  - if `$cat_level_1` contains the category that is being processed, remove the entry at all
  - else add it to the `$cat_level_1` array

Now the `if` condition would be matched **only** if the SQL query returns more then one category with the same `category_id` - which I guess it does not... And if it does then the SQL query is wrong.

I won't ask what for do You need such a logic to be done, but think of few modifications:

- set the `$level` for the query so only the categories of `$level` level are returned
- check all the returned categories and check if there are duplicate entries (the same `category_id` more then once - if so, try using `GROUP BY` clause in Your SQL query
- when joining oc_XXX_description table, always use actual `language_id`!

Then Your query could look like:

```php
$sql = 'SELECT c.category_id, cd.name, cp.level ' .
   'FROM oc_category c ' . 
   'LEFT JOIN c_category_description cd ' .
   'ON cd.category_id = c.category_id AND cd.language_id = ' . $this->config->get('language_id') . 
   'LEFT JOIN oc_category_path cp ' .
   'ON cp.category_id = c.category_id' . 
   'WHERE cp.level = ' . $level;
```

which should produce e.g. this query:

```sql
SELECT c.category_id, cd.name, cp.level
FROM oc_category c
    LEFT JOIN c_category_description cd ON cd.category_id = c.category_id AND cd.language_id = 2
    LEFT JOIN oc_category_path cp ON cp.category_id = c.category_id
WHERE cp.level = 1
```

Now You should not need any PHP `if level` and `if in_array` logic...